# How to make a Workflow in SharePoint Online 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, sharepoint-online

I've been doing some research on how to implement a workflow in SharePoint Online and I found two interesting examples:

1. [First](http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/05/25/how-to-create-sharepoint-2013-workflow-app-site-columns-to-fully-deployed-app-using-visual-studio-2012/)
2. [Second](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn456545(v=office.15).aspx)

They were useful, but there is a big problem with these. They are apps, so the workflow cannot be used outside the app (ex. lists, libraries) is there any way to make this (using Visual Studio, Power shell, SP Designer, etc.)? I am new in SharePoint, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You kan add
true
to the WorkflowManifest in order to publish the workflow om the hostweb. But not that the tasks og history for the workfow is still tracked on the appweb.
You can see example here...
http://www.vrdmn.com/2014/09/integrated-workflow-apps-deploy.html

If you need the tasks and history on the hostweb you can create a sandbox solution with the workflow and publish the wsp-apckage on the site.

If you are not a programmer you're probably better of with SharePoint Designer 2013. You can download that for free. Just make a quick search for SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow. There are plenty of examples for this.